# Permission Denied when I use remove()

Tags: c++, file, delete-file

I have this issue. I have a C++ program; the program successfully make files in which I save records. In one procedure I edit one record and make another file with different name. At the end I close the both files and when I try to delete old one and rename the new one I have this error:

> Error deleting file: Permission denied.

```
void SoldDevices()
{
 int soldQuantity = 0;
 char soldModel[20];
 ElShop tempVar;
 FILE *newFile; 

 printf("Enter model of sold device: ");
 gets(soldModel); 

 file = fopen(fileName, "r+"); 
 fread(&shop, sizeof(shop), 1, file);

 while (!feof(file))
 {
       if (strcmp(shop.model, soldModel) == 0)
       {
             tempVar = shop;
             break;
       }

       fread(&shop, sizeof(shop), 1, file);
 }

 fclose(file);

 printf("Enter how much devices are sold: ");
 scanf("%d", &soldQuantity);

 while (tempVar.quantity < soldQuantity)
 {
       printf("No items available!\n");
       printf("Enter how much devices are sold: ");
       scanf("%d", &soldQuantity);
 }

 tempVar.quantity = tempVar.quantity - soldQuantity;
 printf("%d\n", tempVar.quantity);

 file = fopen(fileName, "rb");
 newFile = fopen("New", "wb");

 fread(&shop, sizeof(shop), 1, file);

 while (!feof(file))
 {
      if(strcmp(soldModel, shop.model) == 0)
      {
          fwrite(&tempVar, sizeof(shop), 1, newFile);
      }
      else
      {
          fwrite(&shop, sizeof(shop), 1, newFile);
      }

      fread(&shop, sizeof(shop), 1, file);
 }
 fclose(newFile); 
 fclose(file);

 if( remove( fileName ) != 0 )
     perror( "Error deleting file" );
 else
     puts( "File successfully deleted" );
 rename("New", fileName);
}
```

Did anyone have some ideas to resolve the problem?

Comment: Do you have sufficiente rights?

Comment: did you try deleting the same file using the command line or files explorer?

Comment: what operating system are you running this on?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 64bit with an administrator account, so I have full rights. 

How to delete file using the command line? When I open project folder and press CTRL + DELETE and file is deleted without any problems.

Comment: I found something interesting. Folder, where I save my project files, have read-only property checked. I unchecked it, press apply, but folder is still read only. I google it and found this 
 [http://www.followsteph.com/2007/06/17/windows-vista-read-only/] . But there isn't any solution. I tried to give full permission to everyone, but I'm with an administrator account so I had them. Some Ideas?! I forget to say that I'm using Dev C++

Answer (score 3):

I once had the same problem like you, but now I had solved it.
You must had some file-pointers that haven't closed when you used `remove()`. It does not have to be in the same .cpp file, maybe in different files.

Take me as an example, I think I had closed the file, but later I found out that I have "return" sentences before `fclose()` which results in the file not being closed correctly.

PS:
1. I have 3 .cpp files.

2. The file containing `remove()` was used after the file(A.cpp) that didn't make the file closed correctly.
3. Because the A.cpp don't closed the file correctly so that the Permission Denied appears.
4. My English is poor. Hope this can help you.